# View/Model data isn't refreshing/changing after post/postback, even though I'm using the PRG pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Update**  I have saved my problem a long time ago.  The problem was that I was trying to call the view model on the wrong view method!  I was calling the base view method (Document), instead of one of it's derived method (like NewDocument, PDFDocument, etc.)  Thus it was only giving me the Documents data, which didn't change. I was looking and using the wrong view method all the time...  Stephen, when you asked me

> "Why do you create derived classes in a method but then return only the base class"

I couldn't answer the question at the time because I didn't even know myself, until I remember that originally, the method wasn't returning the base class. I only changed it so that it can work with the base view method, which was wrong in the first place!

That's what I get for only getting 3-4 hours of sleep in 3 days. Everything works right now. Thanks.

---

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why the data in my view isn't changing after I do a post.  Originally I was doing it via *return View()* and it worked, but since it was a partial view, the page didn't look great, so I was reading up and saw that it was better to do it by Post-Redirect-Get pattern (PRG) and to use an id value to retrieve the values instead of sending the entire model via Tempdata. I even used *ModelState.Clear()* and that didn't even work. When I debugged the code, the model only has the values from when I first called it.

Here's part of my Get controller:

**NewDocument Get Controller**

```
    [DocumentAuthenticationFilter]
    public ActionResult NewDocument(int? id = null)
    {
        // This doesn't work. The view keeps on showing the data from View(Services.CreateNewDocument()).
        if (id != null)
        {
            return View(Services.GetdocumentViewModelData(DocEnum.Section.NEW_DOC_INDEX, (int)id));
        }

        // This works fine
        return View(Services.CreateNewDocument());
    }
```

And here's the post that calls the redirect:

**NewDocument Post controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "AddDocuments")]
    //[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult AddDocumentViewModel(FormCollection frm, DocumentViewModel dvm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int? DocID = Services.AddingNewDocument(dvm);
                // See, I even tried to clear it.
                ModelState.Clear();
                return base.RedirectToAction("NewDocument", new { id = DocID });
            }
            else
            {
               // Display errors in the modal
            }
            return base.RedirectToAction("NewDocument");
        }
```

And here's the old way I did it:

**NewDocument Post controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "AddDocuments")]
    //[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult AddDocumentViewModel(FormCollection frm, DocumentViewModel dvm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Services.AddingNewDocument(ref dvm);
                dvm.NewRecordMode = DocEnum.Action.UPDATE;
                // It worked, but only the partial view showed, and not the entire view.
                return PartialView("_NewDocument", dvm);
            }
            else
            {
               // Display errors in the model
            }
            return base.RedirectToAction("NewDocument");
        }
```

Could it be because I'm using a custom model binding?

**My Custom Model Binding**

```
public class BaseClassModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;

        var modelTypeValue = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("ViewModel");
        if (modelTypeValue == null)
            throw new Exception("View does not contain the needed derived model type name");

        var modelTypeName = modelTypeValue.AttemptedValue;

        var type = modelType.Assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsSubclassOf(modelType) && x.Name == modelTypeName);

        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Derived model type {0} not found", modelTypeName));
        }

        var instance = bindingContext.Model ?? base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => instance, type);

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** And here's the GetDocumentViewModelData code:

**GetDocumentFromViewModelData**

```
 public static DocumentViewModel GetDocumentViewModelData(DocEnum.Section docType, int id)
    {
        switch (docType)
        {
            case DocEnum.Section.NEW_DOCUMENT_INDEX:
                // NewDocumentTypeViewModel  is a child to DocumentTypeViewModel
                DocumentTypeViewModel nd = NewDocumentService.GetViewModelByID(id);
                return nd;
            case DocEnum.Section.PDF_DOCUMENT:
                DocumentTypeViewModel pdfvm = PDFDocumentService.GetViewModelByID(id);
                return pdfvm;
            case DocEnum.Section.XLS_DOCUMENT:
                DocumentTypeViewModel xlsvm = XLSDocumentService.GetViewModelByID(id);
                return xlsvm;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Edit:** Also adding the GetViewModelByID function

**GetViewModelByID**

```
public static DocumentTypeViewModel GetViewModelByID(int id)
    {
        docEntities db = new docEntities();
        NewDocumentTypeViewModel vm = new NewDocumentTypeViewModel();

        // Calls a stored procedure called Select_Documents_ByID(id) to get the note entry
        //   that was submitted.
        List<Select_Documents_ByID_Result> prevNotes = db.Select_Documents_ByID(id).ToList();
        StringBuilder sNotes = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var note in prevNotes)
        {
            sNotes.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}: {2}\n\n", note.CreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), note.username, note.Entry);
        }

        vm.PreviousNotes = sNotes.ToString();

        return vm;
    }
```

**Edit:** I did a direct creation of the view model inside the Get controller, and it's the same result. when i debugged the view itself, the values from the new view model don't show up. Instead, the values from the initial view model, `View(Services.CreateNewDocument())`, shows.

```
    [DocumentAuthenticationFilter]
    public ActionResult NewDocument(int? id = null)
    {
        // Right here I created the view model to test thing, but I'm getting the same results. Nothing has changed.
        if (id != null)
        {
            var d = new NewDocumentTypeViewModel(1, "Help!");
            // This property is from the base class, DocumentTypeViewModel
            d.DocumentTitle = "Testing!";
            return View(d);
            // Inside the view itself, none of the values in the view model, including the one
            // belonging to the base class. It still shows the initial values.
        }

        // This works fine
        // Or maybe not...
        return View(Services.CreateNewDocument());
    }
```

**Edit:** I wanted to see if it was also doing the same thing for the initial call to the view `return View(Services.CreateNewDocument())`, and decided to change the value for `documentTitle` in the base class from `New Document` to a randomly-generated number, after the object has been created.

Here's the code for DocumentTypeViewModel's default constructor:

```
    public DocumentTypeViewModel()
    {
        DocumentTitle = "New Document";
        NewRecordMode = DocEnum.Action.ADD;
        DocumentID = 0;
    }
```

And here's the `Services.CreateNewDocument()` code where I change the DocumentTitle after the View Model has been created.

```
public DocumentTypeViewModel CreateNewDocument()
    {
        DocumentTypeViewModel dtvm = new DocumentTypeViewModel();
        Random r = new Random();
        dtvm.DocumentTitle = r.Next(5, Int32.MaxValue).ToString();
        return dtvm;
    }
```

Now in the View, when I call DocumentTitle:

```
 <div class="label-text-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentTitle)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DocumentTitle)
 </div>
```

You would expect to see a randomly-generated number every time the View gets called. Nope, what you would see is "New Document".  Weird.

It's seems that `Services.GetDocumentViewModelData()` is not exactly working correctly. It only carries the values created by the base class' constructor when a view is created, not any values that have been added or changed within `GetDocumentViewModelData()` itself.  Why is that? What's going on? Please help anybody!

Comment: Not clear what your code is doing. Does `Services.AddingNewDocument(ref dvm);` save something to the database? Why do you then set `dvm.NewRecordMode = DocEnum.Action.UPDATE;` (that value is not being saved anywhere so its immediately lost)? What does `Services.GetdocumentViewModelData(...)` do? And whats the point of `FormCollection frm`?

Comment: Yes, it does save to the database, and then gets the new ID, but that was the old way. As for `dvm.NewRecordMode = DocEnum.Action.UPDATE`, that was to tell the view when the model got sent back that's not in add mode, but in update mode.  I forgot to take it out in the new post controller code when I was tying this. It's not in my code. `Services.GetDocumentViewModelData` gets the data from the newly created document, stores it in a view model, and **supposedly** display it through the view.

Comment: And putting `FormCollection frm` as your first parameter in your post controller had something to do with a security prevention I read a long time ago. I forgot what it was.

Comment: `ModelState.Clear()` is pointless if your redirecting, as is `FormCollection frm` (your already binding the form values to the model). If `Services.GetdocumentViewModelData()` is getting the model you just saved, it should be fine. Since we have no idea what any of these methods do or if that return the correct result, all you can do is debug your code.

Comment: Okay, I added two more pieces of code.

Comment: You really need to reconsider your design. What are all these static methods? and how can (or why would) `public static DocumentViewModel` return `DocumentTypeViewModel`? Just debug and step through your code.

Comment: I did, many times, and I can't solve the problem. `public static DocumentViewModel` is going to be `public override DocumentViewModel`, an interface that other child view models will use. Like a factory.

Comment: Edited GetViewModelByID again.

Comment: Debug again. Same thing.

Comment: Found out something very interesting. I show it at the last edit.

Comment: `Services.GetDocumentViewModelData()` is not exactly working correctly either. It only carries the values created by the base class' constructor when a view is created, not any values that have been added or changed within `GetDocumentViewModelData()` itself.  Why is that? What's going on?

Comment: Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: I doubt any one can help with this. Your design is all wrong. Why do you have all these static methods. Why do you create derived classes in a method but then return only the base class.

Comment: If you can't help me, where can I get help beside SO.

Comment: If my design is wrong, then tell what I should have done. Telling me my design isn't wrong won't cut it. In other words go into details.

Comment: I don't know what your app is or what it does. How can I possibly go into details.

Comment: The reason for static is because I have a lot of functions and I don't want to create a huge object just to call the functions.

Comment: I think you did catch my error. What I was trying to do is do something like a factory with ` GetDocumentViewModelData` returning the derived classes. Instead of `DocumentTypeViewModel nd = NewDocumentService.GetViewModelByID(id);  return nd;`  I should have done `NewDocumentTypeViewModel nd = NewDocumentService.GetViewModelByID(id);  return nd;` I think that would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Look at the **Update** section on top. Thanks Stephen.